# How to remove white flicker / flash while navigating between fragments?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

I've set bottom navigation using Navigation Component, but whenever I navigate between fragments I see a white flicker.

[image]

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.dashboardNavHostFragment)
    bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
}
```

this is how I setup my bottom navigation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setupWithNavController` uses a cross fade animation to swap between tabs as per the [material design guidelines](https://material.io/components/bottom-navigation#behavior). A cross fade means that the previous tab is going from fully opaque to fully transparent while the new tab is going from fully transparent to fully opaque. During the middle of this transition, *both* tabs are semi-transparent. This means that you'll partially see through both of them to see the `android:windowBackground` you've set on your activity.

In your case, it appears that you have a white `windowBackground`, which is where the white flash is coming from.

You should either:

1. Update your activity's theme to use a `Dark` theme, which will give you a dark `windowBackground` by default or
2. Manually update your theme to include a dark background:

```
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/black</item>
```